# Can Yarn and npm be used by multiple developers on the same project?

Tags: node.js, npm, package-managers, yarnpkg

I work in a team of about 20 other developers. All of our projects utilize npm packages and currently all of our developers are running npm to manage those packages. I'm very curious about Yarn and have it currently installed on my machine.  However I'm nervous to actually use it to install packages in case it screws up a project for other developers.

My question is can one developer utilize Yarn on a project while other devs are using npm in the same repo?  From what I've read, Yarn uses the same `package.json` file to get its dependencies. We ignore the node_modules in our repo, however we use `npm shrinkwrap` to lock dependencies. I know Yarn has a `Yarn.lock` file and that is where my concern lies.  Has anyone attempted to run Yarn independently from their team and what issues have you run into?

Answer (score 8):

Yarn doesn't read `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. It generates its own `yarn.lock`. While only you use yarn, the project in your environment might have dependencies version different then that your teammates have. However it's safe to try yarn in your own environment since it doesn't overwrite shrinkwrap file and won't impact other developers.