# Are yarn and npm interchangeable in practice?

Tags: npm, installation, yarnpkg

I have a project with a package.json file and an install bash script that, among other steps, runs `npm install`.

I'm thinking of updating the script so that it runs `yarn install` if [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) is available (to take advantage of yarn's caching, lockfile, etc), and falls back to `npm install` otherwise. As far as I can tell, all the packages seem to install and work ok either way.

Are `yarn` and `npm` interchangeable enough for this to be a viable approach, though? Or are there potential issues that this could lead to? Are we meant to just pick one, or is yarn interchangeable with npm in practice?

(nb. I've read this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309048/yarn-npm-multiple-devs), but I'm asking this as a separate question because it's about explicitly supporting both yarn and npm install processes in a project)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yarn and npm (version >=3.0.0) should be relatively compatible, especially moving from npm *to* Yarn, because compatibility is [one of the stated goals of Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/375). As stated in [Migrating from npm](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm):

> Yarn can consume the same package.json format as npm, and can install any package from the npm registry.

So, in theory, any `package.json` that is valid for npm should also work equally well for Yarn. Note that I say that npm v2 is probably less compatible - this is because npm migrated from a nested `node_modules` structure to a flat layout (which is what Yarn uses). That said, Yarn and npm v3 should produce very similar layouts, because, as stated in the issue [I linked](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/375):

> To a first approximation we should try to be very compatible with the node_modules layout for people who need that compatibility, because it'll be the most likely way to avoid long-tail compatibility problems.

However, you *will not* be able to take advantage of the Yarn.lock generated by Yarn, because (as the name suggests) it's only supported by Yarn, and `npm shrinkwrap` is not compatible.

Also, as noted by @RyanZim, older versions of Yarn don't support [pre- and post-install hooks](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/853), but [versions later than `v0.16.1`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/800) do. If you rely on these hooks, you will need to specify to users that versions greater than `v0.16.1` are required.

In summary, as long as you encounter no bugs and only use features that are shared by both package managers, you should have no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Should add that `yarn` does not support `postinstall` scripts. This isn't an issue for most packages, but there are a few that won't install correctly.

Comment: @RyanZim it appears to have been fixed according to GitHub - do you know if the changes in the main release yet?

Comment: Didn't know that, I don't actually use yarn. I thought yarn was opposed to `postinstall` scripts on the grounds of security. Mind posting a link to the relevant thread on Github here?

Comment: The PR is [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/800) - it looks like they had a change of heart. I'll test this myself if you haven't got yarn installed and update the post as appropriate.

Comment: @RyanZim just tested by installing the `bcrypt` package which uses `node-gyp` - works fine as of v0.16.1.